# Withdraw from parachain to relay chain (XCM)

Tags: polkadot-js, xcm

We have local testnet with our parachain and we successfully sent KSM from relay to parachain. We have however the problem when we want to withdraw KSM back from parachain to relay chain. We always receive the error **UntrustedReserveLocation**

Steps:
On the relay chain we set the default xcm version to 1.

**xcmPallet -> forceDefaultXcmVersion**, set the **maybeXcmVersion** field to **1**

We construct the extrinsic in this form

```
const hexAccount = api.createType('AccountId32', 'some address here').toHex()

const dest = {
    V1: {
      parents: 1,
      interior: 'Here',
    },
}

const beneficiary = {
      V1: {
        parents: 1,
        interior: {
          X1: {
            AccountId32: {
              network: 'Any',
              id: hexAccount,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }

const assets = {
      V1: [
        {
          id: {
            Concrete: {
              parents: 1,
              interior: 'Here',
            },
          },
          fun: {
            Fungible: HERE_IS_THE_AMOUNT,
          },
        },
      ],
    }
```

and then we execute tx

```
api.tx.polkadotXcm
    .reserveTransferAssets(dest, beneficiary, assets, '0')
    .signAndSend('some address here')
```

Can someone tells what could be the problem ? Thanks

Comment: Could you add your `xcm_executor` config in your `xcm_config` for both runtimes, para and relay, please.

Although, consider teleporting for "moving" the relay's native token to a parachain and back.

Comment: Hi @AlejandroMartinez is this enough ? https://github.com/mangata-finance/mangata-node/blob/develop/runtime/mangata-rococo/src/lib.rs#L1244-L1263 ? ..for relay chain we are using docker image for testing parity/polkadot:v0.9.22  so that should be https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/v0.9.22/runtime/rococo/src/lib.rs

Comment: @AlejandroMartínez

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relay Chain does not recognize any other chain as a reserve: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/xcm_config.rs#L137

Therefore, when it receives a `ReserveAssetDeposited`, it will fail with `UntrustedReserveLocation`: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L288-L291

If you want to reserve transfer back you shouldn't send a `ReserveAssetDeposited`, you should make use of `InitiateReserveWithdraw`. Unfortunately, there is not yet any dispatchable in `pallet-xcm` to perform it, but you can find an example in `xTokens`: https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/c439a50e01944aedeef33231e0824a17ed1813bc/xtokens/src/lib.rs#L659-L677

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. Exactly what you describe we used now xTokens and we were able to withdraw KSM from parachain to relay chain. Thanks

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you! Very useful!

Comment: @NachoPal, your answer is really helpful. I guess `InitiateReserveWithdraw` is more suitable because otherwise, we would end up doubling tokens as they are stored in the sovereign account of the destination chain every time we do `ReserveAssetDeposited`. Or am I wrong?